# SQL Server 2012 - Doing structure validation before insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to insert data from a dirty staging table into a clean staging table. The catch is that if any data in the dirty staging table doesn't match the length / datatype of the corresponding column in the clean staging table, then it should be captured and inserted into an error table.

So basically, lets assume this is my dirty staging table - `T_DSTG_Employees` with two columns `Empid` and `EmpName`, and let's assume my clean staging table `T_CSTG_Employees` has the same two columns. The `EmpName` column in clean staging is of datatype `nvarchar(30)`, so any record in the dirty staging that is over 30 characters in length should go into the error table.

What would be the best way to do this without impacting performance too much? There might be scenarios where the program might insert close to 1 million records. Would a trigger be optimal?

Comment: I am not sure how are you moving the data but I think you need to write the data move logic in such a way that it validates the data first and moves the invalid data into error then move valid data into clean staging table.

Comment: Why do you have two staging tables? Is the sanitation process really that complicated that you need to do it in two parts? Usually, one staging table and one production table is enough.....

Comment: @ZoharPeled: There is a windows service that I don't control that loads data into the first staging table from excel sheets. The main processing happens during data load from clean staging to production and I didn't want unsanitized data at this juncture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trigger or a separated stored procedure. I guess it will be clear to add another column

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
ADD [IsRowValud] BIT NULL;
```

Then create another process responsible for validating the rows. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ValidateRows]
AS
BEGIN;

    UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
    SET [IsRowValid] = IIF(LEN(ColA) > 30 OR (TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, ColB) IS NULL AND Colb IS NOT NULL) OR ..., 0, 1)
    WHERE [isRowValid] IS NULL;

END;
```

Then use another routine to insert rows in the error staging table where `isRowValid = 0` and in the correct data table where `isRowValid = 1`.

You can create index on `isRowValid` column and test if it will optimize some of the operations (for example if very small range of the data has `isRowValid = 0`, you can create filter index in order to optimize the insert into the `error` table).

Comment: If you are going to add another column (which is not a bad idea), you might as well make it a persisted computed column instead of running an update statement...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I agree. I am just not familiar with the logic of validating a row - there might be many columns or complex validation and having a persisted column might delay the initial insert process. If this is not the case, having a persisted column is more clear.

Comment: I'll give this a try today. The only thing is, I don't want to hardcode either data-type or length in the SP just in case the table structure changes in future. There are also a lot of staging tables, so am thinking to make the SP dynamic and make it retrieve table defintions and form the update query. Will let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: @user3324321 You should be able to to this - in `sys.columns` and `sys.types` you can get the `target type` and use `LEN` or `TRY_CONVERT` for the input data. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'll avoid this approach and make a different one. So, instead of validation while moving data (which will be a pain on the neck), I would create a store procedure to validate all existed records on the dirty staging table according to the new clean table requirements. Then, Insert those unmatched records (hence, errors) into a new table (something like Employees_Unmatched). When I'm done verifying all existing records, I just do a simple insert and exclude all records that are existed in the unmatched records table (Employees_Unmatched), and then, I go back to the unmatched records table, and work on fixing the records as needed to be inserted into the final table.

This way I avoid any type of conversion errors, and also I make sure to the relation is intact for each column, as there might be new or unused columns or some structure changes on each table.

The validation part could be manual (you define your own logic for each table), or you can have the help of `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` (linked their object_id) to get both tables columns and compare their differences or could be both (whatever works best for your situation).